# Perron's formula analogue for function fields

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I've used Perron's formula before as an analytic tool, but I was wondering if it's possible to apply an analogue of Perron's formula on a function field? If so, does anyone have a reference for this?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can find an example in this paper http://www.ccms.or.kr/data/pdfpaper/jcms30_1/30_1_15.pdf . See also https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323180715_Mean_value_of_the_class_number_in_function_fields_revisited , Lemma $4.1$

Comment: @MarcoCantarini yep. I also used this in my paper on the Mertens conjecture for elliptic curves over function fields. It’s just Cauchy’s residue theorem.